# Required Parameter Missing Error (PUT Request)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, spotify, put

I keep on getting this error when I make this PUT request.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "Required parameter position_ms missing"
  }
}
```

The format I'm using is the same that I've been using for all the previous PUT requests and progress exists right before I make the call so I'm not sure what's going on

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/seek',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   type: 'PUT',
   dataType: 'json',
   headers: {
   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
},
data: JSON.stringify({'position_ms':progress, "device_id":deviceID}),
      success: function(response) {
      }
});
```

Request Payload:

```
{position_ms: 78659, device_id: "9e485fc5aa0b4f0bce19f53571398003ee05d6f5"}
```

> device_id : "9e485fc5aa0b4f0bce19f53571398003ee05d6f5" position_ms :
>   78659

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({'position_ms':progress, "device_id":deviceID}),` remove `JSON.stringify` from this line because it create string from json. Send json as it is `data: {'position_ms':progress, "device_id":deviceID},`

Comment: What should I change the content type to? Or should I remove it?

Comment: Still didn't work

Comment: What you have done?

Comment: I removed the JSON.stringify and just sent it as an object. Removed the ContentType header and also printed out the type of progress just to make sure it isn't a string and it's of type 'number'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a query string and added it to the url and it worked!

```
                              $.ajax({
                                url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/seek' + '?' + $.param(seekPos),
                                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                type: 'PUT',
                                headers: {
                                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                                },
                                data: {'device_id':deviceID},
                                success: function(response) {
                                }
                              });
```